# Wordpress - Load Custom Post Type on front-page.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to load a single custom post type as my homepage. Not an archive but a single post, ID 10190. Looking to do this without a redirect for SEO reasons. What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: you are still confused about what you want to do. Describe your question in some more brief.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so_48395149' );

function so_48395149() {
    global $post;
    if( is_front_page() ) {
        $post = get_post( 10190 );
    }
}
```

*Note: I haven't tested this, but you'll be wanting something along these lines.*

WordPress stores the currently viewed post in a global `$post` variable. In this case, we want to overwrite that with the specified post [type] only on the front page. We use the `template_redirect` hook as it's one of the last hooks available before the HTML is generated.